Why 発狂する rather than 発狂になる?

鏡が映すものが現実のものか、はたして可能なものなのかさえ判断できす、みんな鏡の前でヘトヘトになったり、鏡に映る姿に魅入られてしまったり、発狂したりしたんじゃよ。
Without even being able to judge whether the things reflected in the mirror are real or even possible, everyone gets exhausted in front of it, becomes entranced by the image reflected in it, and goes mad.

I'm confused by the use of する in 発狂したり. I don't know if I'm failing to keep up with the topic in this sentence, but I would have expected 発狂になったり. That is to say, people become mad rather than the mirror makes them mad. What am I missing?

発狂 is the "act of becoming mad", you don't become the act of becoming mad, it's something you do.

If you have seen it defined as "madness" somewhere, it's simply wrong.

発狂になる is plain wrong. 発狂する is an intransitive verb, and you have to remember how it's used. Its wago counterpart, 狂う, has always been intransitive since ancient times. You know the transitivity of a verb is not always preserved between English and Japanese, right? 驚く in Japanese is "to be surprised" in English, and 興奮する is "to become excited".
